Two axis inclinometer rotation matrix
The goal is to use a dual axis inclinometer to calibrate for pedestal mislevel when computing the azimuth and elevation pointing angle of the pedestal when pointing at a long distance target. Given the orientation of a 2 axis inclinometer with respect to pedestal given below, how can I use the angles of the inclinometer to calculate the corrections to be applied to the azimuth and elevation angles of the pedestal in order to remove the impact of the pedestal misalignment with respect to horizontal plane? The idea is to take measurements from the two axis inclinometer at multiple azimuth angles to reduce measurement error/noise.

